# Calculate offsets of structure members without instantiation

Tags: c++

What about this code, is it standard ? I've seen that kind of code in a Visual C++ header, it can calculate the offsets of some structure members but how does it works exactly ?

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};


int main(int argc, char** argv)      
{
    int* i1 = (&((Foo*)0)->a);
    int* i2 = (&((Foo*)0)->b);
    int* i3 = (&((Foo*)0)->c);

    std::cout << "i1 = " << i1 << "\ni2 = " << i2 << "\ni3 = " << i3 << "\n";
    return 0;
}

Results : i1 = 0, i2 = 4, i3 = 8
```

Edit :
Just remembered where I saw this code before. It's in `WinNT.h`

```
#define FIELD_OFFSET(type, field)    ((LONG)(LONG_PTR)&(((type *)0)->field))
```

Comment: There is a standard macro `offsetof(structure,field)` defined in `<cstddef>`, which is doing just that. So yes, the code is valid, but using the standard macro would make it more standard.

Comment: TL;DR: The implementation can do stuff like that, you can't.

Comment: What do you mean by I can't, I can do it, my program works.

Comment: @nikau6 You "can" also run red lights, that works too (most of the time). Does not mean it's legal or a good idea though.

Comment: That was my question, is it standard ? Previous answer said it's valid. It's valid or it's not, it can't be both.

Comment: As the answers in the dupe explain, it's valid when the implementation does it as long as it works, it's not valid when you do it.

Comment: So it's implementation dependant, got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is pretty common, as macro offsetof. Take a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof.

It works as the distance of each member's memory location and  struct's memory location. In case of your example, you set struct's memory location as 0, thus no need to calculate distance.

Comment: If you set your memory location as 0 ... wouldn't the operator "->" be segmentation fault?

Comment: segfault happens when you are actually trying to access the member variable or call the member function. With &, you are just calculating memory address.

Comment: Even starting at location 0 it can still be useful to calculate the offsets.